# PringNG tab menu

Tags: angular, angular8, primeng

How to load different components in primeNG tab menu

Currently, I am using the routing, is there any other good way?

**HTML File**

```
<p-tabView (onChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let item of tabs; let i = index">
    <p-tabPanel [header]="item.label" [selected]="i == 0" [disabled]="item.isDisabled" *ngIf="item.isVisible">
    </p-tabPanel>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</p-tabView>
```

**TS file code:**

```
export class TabViewComponent implements OnChanges {
       onTabChange(event: any) {
        console.log(event);
           this.router.navigate([this.tabs[event.index].route],
            { relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange: true, preserveQueryParams: true });                 
      } 

}
```

Comment: Why don't you embed component's selector inside p-tabPanel?

Comment: By this way dynamically load the component in router outlet which is my requirement and do't need to add selector after creating new component.